# Clone a Github repo using SSH

Tags: github, ssh, clone, git-clone

I am trying recently to clone some Github repo using SSH but unfortunately, I don't see anymore the clone with SSH option. Clone with HTTPS is the single clone option available. Does anyone faced the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option appears if you are logged in with a user that has a SSH key set up in the profile.

Answer (score 0):

The option is normally located under *clone or download* option.

[image: Screenshot about how to clone via ssh a github repo]
Maybe the repository that you want to clone have this feature disabled.